# Create a mysql date from month and year

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a value like so:

```
month: 5
year: 2002
```

How can I use PHP to get this as a MySQL datestamp?

If I use the standard date() function `$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`, I need to add the other fields.

Comment: Why not always use 1 for the day and 00:00:00 for the time?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you;re asking but I *think* this is what you're looking for.

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-n', '2002-5');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a timestamp:

```
<?php echo strtotime(date('2002-5-1')); ?>
```

If you want a datetime:

```
<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('2002-5-1'));?>
```

Although you just can use

```
<?php $datetime = "2002-5-1 00:00:00";?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a day with value of 1:

```
$mysqlDate = sprintf("%d-%d-%d", $year, $month, 1);
```

Does it work for you?